# Sum of discrete Gaussian series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, approximation, exponential-sum

Is there a sum formula for the following sequence?

It is a Gaussian with $N$ terms, $x_{0}$ and $\sigma$ are real numbers, with $0<x_{0}<N$

$$\sum_{x=0}^{N-1} e^{\frac{-1}{\sigma} \:(x-x_{0})^{2}}$$

I was looking for a formula like [these ones](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFormulas.html), but if not possible some approximation is Ok.

Comment: I think that the expression would be clearer if written $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-(ak+b)^2}.$$ I doubt there is a closed-form.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can easily tame this sum.

For large $\sigma$, the $n$ Gaussians are much overlapping, giving a Gaussian-like shape. But for small $\sigma$, the Gaussians are apart. For intermediate values, you get a partial overlap and the function is irregularly oscillating.

The curves below are obtained by varying $x_0$, for different $\sigma$.

[image]

There could be an approach by finding a smooth, unimodal function that crosses the curve at the inflection points, and subtract it to get the oscillating component.

Then by fitting a curve to the positions of the zeroes, one could find a phase function, which should be quasi-linear. Then by taking the ratio with a sinusoid applied to that phase function, one should find a smooth amplitude envelope. The approximation would have the form

$$u(x_0)+a(x_0)\cos(\phi(x_0))$$
where $u,a,\phi$ themselves depend on $\sigma$.

Comment: What is exactly $x$ and $y$ in that plot?

Comment: But in my question $x$ takes the values $0,1,2,...,N-1$. How do you get a continuous function?

Comment: @Brenlla: oops, sorry, the curves are functions of $x_0$, for different $\sigma$. You were asking to evaluate $\Sigma(x_0,\sigma)$.